# How to align items in two cards side by side

Tags: html, css

How can I align booth names in the same line ?

[image]

The image above show the problem. I tried to use flex-box but is not working. I would like to position "John Dean" in the bottom of all cards. Depending the size of the p tag the names have differente positions.

```css
.test {
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
   
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 50%;
}

.card h3 {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 8px 0;
/*   line-height: 20px !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important; */
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card .container {
  padding: 2px 14px;
}

.card p {
  margin: 14px 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Card</h2>

<div class="test">

<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/9YWv-qOa9uW7CQZ9UGiW23eTZzU=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/BTCNJJN2Y43KPHPXPQWPASXRKM.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
  <p>
  Lorem Ipsum ie like Aldus Pa
  geMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
    <h4>john dean</h4>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/9YWv-qOa9uW7CQZ9UGiW23eTZzU=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/BTCNJJN2Y43KPHPXPQWPASXRKM.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
   <p>
  Lorem Ipsum ie like Aldus Pa
  geMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum ie like Aldus Pa
  geMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
    <h4>john dean</h4>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `card` and the inner `container` flex-columns, then tell the `container` to xpand as much as possible with `flex:1`.

Then push the `h4` to the bottom of the container with `margin-top:auto`.

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card h3 {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  /*   line-height: 20px !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important; */
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card .container {
  padding: 2px 14px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card h4 {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.card p {
  margin: 14px 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Card</h2>

<div class="test">

  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/9YWv-qOa9uW7CQZ9UGiW23eTZzU=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/BTCNJJN2Y43KPHPXPQWPASXRKM.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum ie like Aldus Pa geMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <h4>john dean</h4>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/9YWv-qOa9uW7CQZ9UGiW23eTZzU=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/BTCNJJN2Y43KPHPXPQWPASXRKM.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum ie like Aldus Pa geMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum ie like Aldus Pa geMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <h4>john dean</h4>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `display: flex` will do the trick for you. Making `card` flex with container and expanding both `card` and `container` with `flex: 1` will push make content expand, pushing `p` to the bottom.

```css
.test {
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
   
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.2s;
  width: 50%;
}

.card h3 {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 8px 0;
/*   line-height: 20px !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important; */
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card .container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2px 14px;
}

.card p {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 14px 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Card</h2>

<div class="test">

<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/9YWv-qOa9uW7CQZ9UGiW23eTZzU=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/BTCNJJN2Y43KPHPXPQWPASXRKM.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
  <p>
  Lorem Ipsum ie like Aldus Pa
  geMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
    <h4>john dean</h4>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/9YWv-qOa9uW7CQZ9UGiW23eTZzU=/1484x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/BTCNJJN2Y43KPHPXPQWPASXRKM.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
   <p>
  Lorem Ipsum ie like Aldus Pa
  geMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum ie like Aldus Pa
  geMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
    <h4>john dean</h4>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```